# I'm Looking for datasets that include images of Egyptian historical landmarks, artifacts, and other tourist attractions

Tags: python, dataset, conv-neural-network, yolo, faster-rcnn

I'm developing an object detection application for tourist assistance using technologies like YOLO and Faster R-CN. I'm Looking for datasets that include images of Egyptian historical landmarks, artifacts, and other tourist attractions. The dataset must be diverse and representative of the types of objects.

thank you,

I'm looking for an image dataset

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)